# Expanding a vector in Matlab ... having some difficulties

Tags: matlab

How can I do the following:

Say that I start with a vector with the elements [5 3 4 9 10] - think of these numbers like daily stock prices. I want to transform this vector into (an approx.) of intraday stock prices - 1/10 of day.

Therefore my vector should look like [ **5** 4.8 4.6 4.4 .4.2 4 3.8 3.6 3.4 3.2 **3** 3.1 3.2 3.3 3.4 3.5 3.6 3.7 3.8 3.9 **4** 4.5 5 5.5 6 6.5 7 7.5 8 8.5 **9** 9.1 9.2 9.3 9.4 9.5 9.6 9.7 9.8 9 **10**]

THank you!!

Comment: Use `interp1`: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/interp1.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

help interp1

You will be using the 'linear' interpolation method.

Thus, initially, you would have

```
x = 0:4;
y = [5 3 4 9 10];
```

Now, interpolate.

```
xnew = 0:.1:4;
ynew = interp1(x,y,xnew,'linear');
```

Comment: [The online documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/interp1.html) has some more examples.